# Gmail filter to match all incoming messages

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I would like to apply a particular label to all incoming messages. Gmail filters apply to both outgoing and incoming messages. So I've added a condition that says `Doesn't have from:me`. This prevents the filter from matching outgoing messages in Sent. However, it also (undesirably) prevents it from matching incoming messages that I send to myself or that someone else has sent to me “from” my own address. Is there a way to only exclude my own outgoing messages?

I’ve seen mention of using `in:sent` and `label:sent`, but when creating the filter Gmail warns against this saying that they aren’t applied yet at the time the filter is evaluated. I guess they are only for searching after the fact.

Comment: Why not make the condition "to:me" rather than "Doesn't have from:me"?  If you filter on "to:me", that will only capture incoming mail but will not filter out mail you've sent to yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the condition "to:me" instead of "Doesn't have from:me".  This will capture incoming mail and exclude outgoing mail unless you've sent it to yourself.

To include e-mails sent to a mailing list of which you are a recipient, you need to use the "deliveredto:" operator. We can take advantage of the fact that the `Has the words:` field accepts search operators. Leaving the other fields blank, put the following text in the `Has the words:` box: `{(to:YOU@gmail.com) (deliveredto:YOU@gmail.com)}` The inner parenthesis mean that the field is optional (e.g., the mail can be `to:` this address OR it can be `deliveredto:` this address).  This is what your filter should look like:

[image: Filter settings window]

I believe you only need "to:" in order to capture e-mails sent to yourself, although I'd have to test it more to be sure.  Regardless, putting both should capture all incoming e-mail.

Comment: I don’t think that will match messages where my address is not in the To field, e.g. mailing list messages. Also, it *will* match both copies of messages that I send to myself.

Comment: Very true. To include those, we can take advantage of the fact that the Has the words: field accepts search operators. Leaving the other fields blank, put the following text in the `Has the words:` box: {(to:YOU@gmail.com) (deliveredto:YOU@gmail.com)} The inner parenthesis mean that the field is optional (e.g., the mail can be to: this address OR it can be deliveredto: this address).  It makes sense that it would match both copies of email sent to yourself, I'm not sure how you'd avoid that particular edge case.

Comment: Actually, to be honest I'm not sure what you mean when you say it matches "both copies".  When I test sending an e-mail to myself in Gmail, only 1 copy seems to be generated (which is both the sent and received e-mail).

Comment: Hi @MichaelTsai, if this answers your question please mark it as correct, or if not let me know what it does not accomplish based on your original question

Comment: I'm in the process of testing your suggestion. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like the "to:" is necessary to catch messages sent to yourself from within Gmail. Oddly, it also seems to match messages that you bcc to yourself.

Comment: That's true. Are you trying to exclude those?  Otherwise please accept this answer before the bounty expires if it answers your original question.  If you are trying to exclude them, you can use something like this:  `{(to:YOU@gmail.com) (deliveredto:YOU@gmail.com)} -{bcc:YOU@gmail.com} -in:chats`... note the `-` (dash) before the BCC option.  Here's a good list of Gmail's search operators from Google:  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

Comment: No, I’m not trying to exclude them. I just thought it was interesting that “deliveredto:” doesn’t work for messages sent from Gmail. Thanks for your help. I have awarded you the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a few options.

For each example just paste into the Gmail search bar, hit enter to return results and then click the "Show search options" icon on the right hand side which will allow you to create a filter from your search.

1. After early date: `after:1984/04/01`
2. Doesn't contain random string: `-fc1e258c565f4574a2c15b33c63b521a`
3. Larger than zero bytes: `{size:0 is:chats}` (chats have no size)
4. Collectively exhaustive OR filter: `{has:nouserlabels has:userlabels}`
5. All of the above. Create multiple filters, just in case.

I would also be tempted to create a second version of each filter with `in:anywhere` added. This is because there is conflicting info about how these work so best to hedge your bets:

1. `after:1984/04/01 in:anywhere`
2. `-fc1e258c565f4574a2c15b33c63b521a in:anywhere`
3. `{size:0 is:chats} in:anywhere`
4. `{has:nouserlabels has:userlabels} in:anywhere`

List and explanation of available search terms [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en-GB)

#1 and #3 in the first list will warn that the filter won't match incoming mail and yet they do for me without fail. Perhaps it depends on what actions you choose to take.

Comment: I love the idea to create a completely exhaustive OR filter.  That is the most robust and complete solution I've found anywhere online and works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Filters apply labels to incoming messages but if you are using the conversation view it could appear that the label was assigned to the whole conversation instead of a single message.

If you want to check the above by yourself by using the Gmail web app, first turn off the conversation view as is explained on [How to filter by messages, not by conversation?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/13290/88163)

Comment: I don’t think the problem I’m seeing is related to conversations. Filters really do seem to apply to lone outgoing messages with a unique subject.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a solid solution for your older e-mails but a concrete one for your future ones.

**You mention**:

> However, it also (undesirably) prevents it from matching incoming
>   messages that I send to myself or that someone else has sent to me
>   “from” my own address. Is there a way to only exclude my own outgoing
>   messages?

## For future e-mails

We will reverse the whole idea. Instead of excluding your own outgoing messages you can **create a new address** you will be using to send e-mails to yourself. Even better you can have friends send or anyone else to it as well.

We can do that because **Gmail will not acknowledge periods as characters in addresses**.

***Example:***

Let us say your Gmail account is under **`myname@gmail.com`**.

- An e-mail like **`my.name@gmail.com`** will still come to the same inbox.
- The same as **`my.na.me@gmail.com`**
- Or **`m.y.name@gmail.com`**
- Even **`m.y.n.a.m.e.@gmail.com`**

Starting now, you can e-mail yourself to **`my.name@gmail.com`** or have someone else send an e-mail to you “from” your own address. Filter, star, label these messages with ease. *You can find more information about using dots in Gmail addresses [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7436150?hl=en-GB)*.

As for older messages, find them (or whenever you come across one) and forward them to your new address. Your corresponding filters will be automatically applied to them as well.

#### Note

Some people may get confused by using dots in the e-mails. If this is the case please use a different approach to a possible solution for your issue described [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/120238/117311).

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I only need it to work for future messages, but I need a solution that doesn’t require changing my address.

Comment: @MichaelTsai _"...but I need a solution that doesn’t require changing my address"_. I am afraid you misunderstood. You wouldn't change your address for anyone else. It would be just **you** who would email **yourself** to the **same address** with an **extra point** in it. Anyway. Please let us know if the solution provided by Mark works.